# How to install libgpiod binary in /usr/bin in yocto operating system?

Tags: embedded-linux, yocto, gpio, beagleboneblack, bitbake

i am experimenting libgpiod with beaglebone yocto, i get the recipes from

https://github.com/openembedded/meta-openembedded/tree/master/meta-oe/recipes-support/libgpiod

after bitbake libgpiod i observe the some of libgpiod binaries such as gpiodetect, gpioinfo,gpioget,gpioset ,gpiomon,gpiofind is located at

/home/kjlau/yocto_build/build/tmp/work/cortexa8hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/libgpiod/1.4.3-r0/image/usr/bin

May i know how to make it available in /usr/bin directory of begaglebone yocto?

Also, is it ok for me scp all those binaries from host to beaglebone /tmp and execute it? i tried execute
gpioinfo, below is my result. Kindly correct me if i not suppose to do that.
I was expecting result as shown in this link https://beagleboard.org/p/silver2row/the-new-character-device-idea-0968d6

```
root@beagleboneYocto:/tmp# ./gpioinfo
gpiochip0 - 32 lines:
        line   0:      unnamed       unused   input  active-high
        line   1:      unnamed       unused   input  active-high
        line   2:      unnamed       unused   input  active-high
        line   3:      unnamed       unused   input  active-high
        line   4:      unnamed       unused   input  active-high
        line   5:      unnamed       unused   input  active-high
        line   6:      unnamed         "cd"   input   active-low [used]
        line   7:      unnamed       unused   input  active-high
        line   8:      unnamed       unused   input  active-high
        line   9:      unnamed       unused   input  active-high
        line  10:      unnamed       unused   input  active-high
        line  11:      unnamed       unused   input  active-high
        line  12:      unnamed       unused   input  active-high
        line  13:      unnamed       unused   input  active-high
        line  14:      unnamed       unused   input  active-high
        line  15:      unnamed       unused   input  active-high
        line  16:      unnamed       unused   input  active-high
        line  17:      unnamed       unused   input  active-high
        line  18:      unnamed       unused   input  active-high
        line  19:      unnamed       unused   input  active-high
        line  20:      unnamed       unused   input  active-high
        line  21:      unnamed       unused   input  active-high
        line  22:      unnamed       unused   input  active-high
        line  23:      unnamed       unused   input  active-high
        line  24:      unnamed       unused   input  active-high
        line  25:      unnamed       unused   input  active-high
        line  26:      unnamed       unused   input  active-high
        line  27:      unnamed       unused   input  active-high
        line  28:      unnamed       unused   input  active-high
        line  29:      unnamed       unused   input  active-high
        line  30:      unnamed       unused   input  active-high
        line  31:      unnamed       unused   input  active-high
gpiochip1 - 32 lines:
        line   0:      unnamed       unused   input  active-high
        line   1:      unnamed       unused   input  active-high
        line   2:      unnamed       unused   input  active-high
        line   3:      unnamed       unused   input  active-high
        line   4:      unnamed       unused   input  active-high
        line   5:      unnamed       unused   input  active-high
        line   6:      unnamed       unused   input  active-high
        line   7:      unnamed       unused   input  active-high
        line   8:      unnamed       unused   input  active-high
        line   9:      unnamed       unused   input  active-high
        line  10:      unnamed       unused   input  active-high
        line  11:      unnamed       unused   input  active-high
        line  12:      unnamed       unused   input  active-high
        line  13:      unnamed       unused   input  active-high
        line  14:      unnamed       unused   input  active-high
        line  15:      unnamed       unused   input  active-high
        line  16:      unnamed       unused   input  active-high
        line  17:      unnamed       unused   input  active-high
        line  18:      unnamed       unused   input  active-high
        line  19:      unnamed       unused   input  active-high
        line  20:      unnamed       unused   input  active-high
        line  21:      unnamed       unused   input  active-high
        line  22:      unnamed       unused   input  active-high
        line  23:      unnamed       unused   input  active-high
        line  24:      unnamed       unused   input  active-high
        line  25:      unnamed       unused   input  active-high
        line  26:      unnamed       unused   input  active-high
        line  27:      unnamed     "enable"  output  active-high [used]
        line  28:      unnamed       unused   input  active-high
        line  29:      unnamed       unused   input  active-high
        line  30:      unnamed       unused   input  active-high
        line  31:      unnamed       unused   input  active-high
gpiochip2 - 32 lines:
        line   0:      unnamed       unused   input  active-high
        line   1:      unnamed       unused   input  active-high
        line   2:      unnamed       unused   input  active-high
        line   3:      unnamed       unused   input  active-high
        line   4:      unnamed       unused   input  active-high
        line   5:      unnamed       unused   input  active-high
        line   6:      unnamed       unused   input  active-high
        line   7:      unnamed       unused   input  active-high
        line   8:      unnamed       unused   input  active-high
        line   9:      unnamed       unused   input  active-high
        line  10:      unnamed       unused   input  active-high
        line  11:      unnamed       unused   input  active-high
        line  12:      unnamed       unused   input  active-high
        line  13:      unnamed       unused   input  active-high
        line  14:      unnamed       unused   input  active-high
        line  15:      unnamed       unused   input  active-high
        line  16:      unnamed       unused   input  active-high
        line  17:      unnamed       unused   input  active-high
        line  18:      unnamed       unused   input  active-high
        line  19:      unnamed       unused   input  active-high
        line  20:      unnamed       unused   input  active-high
        line  21:      unnamed       unused   input  active-high
        line  22:      unnamed       unused   input  active-high
        line  23:      unnamed       unused   input  active-high
        line  24:      unnamed       unused   input  active-high
        line  25:      unnamed       unused   input  active-high
        line  26:      unnamed       unused   input  active-high
        line  27:      unnamed       unused   input  active-high
        line  28:      unnamed       unused   input  active-high
        line  29:      unnamed       unused   input  active-high
        line  30:      unnamed       unused   input  active-high
        line  31:      unnamed       unused   input  active-high
gpiochip3 - 32 lines:
        line   0:      unnamed       unused   input  active-high
        line   1:      unnamed       unused   input  active-high
        line   2:      unnamed       unused   input  active-high
        line   3:      unnamed       unused   input  active-high
        line   4:      unnamed       unused   input  active-high
        line   5:      unnamed       unused   input  active-high
        line   6:      unnamed       unused   input  active-high
        line   7:      unnamed       unused   input  active-high
        line   8:      unnamed       unused   input  active-high
        line   9:      unnamed       unused   input  active-high
        line  10:      unnamed       unused   input  active-high
        line  11:      unnamed       unused   input  active-high
        line  12:      unnamed       unused   input  active-high
        line  13:      unnamed       unused   input  active-high
        line  14:      unnamed       unused   input  active-high
        line  15:      unnamed       unused   input  active-high
        line  16:      unnamed       unused   input  active-high
        line  17:      unnamed       unused   input  active-high
        line  18:      unnamed       unused   input  active-high
        line  19:      unnamed       unused   input  active-high
        line  20:      unnamed       unused   input  active-high
        line  21:      unnamed       unused   input  active-high
        line  22:      unnamed       unused   input  active-high
        line  23:      unnamed       unused   input  active-high
        line  24:      unnamed       unused   input  active-high
        line  25:      unnamed       unused   input  active-high
        line  26:      unnamed       unused   input  active-high
        line  27:      unnamed       unused   input  active-high
        line  28:      unnamed       unused   input  active-high
        line  29:      unnamed       unused   input  active-high
        line  30:      unnamed       unused   input  active-high
        line  31:      unnamed       unused   input  active-high
```

Comment: The purpose of yocto is to build an image containing all your desired packages (like libgpio and its binaries in your case). So the common way would be to copy the built image to the SD card your beaglebone boots from - if done right, the installed tools are available within the rootfs and you don't have to manually copy them to your target

Comment: hi @Odysseus , ya agree.Just that i pretty rookies on this, may i ask will there there any issue such as i scp these binaries  and executed it on the board ?

Comment: Especially for testing purposes I guess that's absolutely legit - but you might run into issues that you missed to copy some needed library e.g. and it could be really messy if you do it this way for multiple programs/libs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You still have to add the recipe to your image.
This can be done with 'IMAGE_INSTALL_append = " libgpiod"' in the local.conf to start.
A better place would be a image.bb file.

You can check slide 65 of the [Yocto training](https://bootlin.com/doc/training/yocto/yocto-slides.pdf) of Bootlin.com for more info.

Comment: actually i already done that, when i run gpioinfo it does not return me anything, that why i scp the binaries  to the board instead

Comment: Strange i check again this morning, it was installed.i am not sure what going yesterday. But solutions should be around your input. Thanks

Answer (score 5):

I had started looking through the BB file of libgpiod and saw section that looked like install directories and it had the library and tools but the package name for the tools was $PN_tools (or some such).

So I added

```
IMAGE_INSTALL_append = " libgpiod libgpiod-tools"
```

to the bb file for the image and guess what... That copied the tools to the image. Never in a million years would I have figured this out from the documentation, at least the documentation I found.

Comment: user15997517, this does not provide an answer to the question. You can [search for similar questions](/search), or refer to the related and linked questions on the right-hand side of the page to find an answer. If you have a related but different question, [ask a new question](/questions/ask), and include a link to this one to help provide context. See: [Ask questions, get answers, no distractions](/tour),   [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 3):

Adding just `libgpio` is not enough - you will need `libgpiod-tools` and `libgpiod-dev` to build this properly.

I have added :

```
IMAGE_INSTALL_append = " libgpiod libgpiod-tools libgpiod-dev"
```

to my `local.conf` file and got the package build properly in `/usr/bin` directory.

Platform: `Apalis IMX8`, OS: `TorizonCore`.